# Posting to Twitter using SLComposeViewController not working on iOS 8 devices

Tags: objective-c, iphone, twitter, ios8, slcomposeviewcontroller

I use the following code to post to Twitter.

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Sample post string"];
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works fine on iOS 7 devices. For iOS 8 devices, tapping Post button shows this alert.

[image]

Moreover console prints this message `plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated`

I went through these links

1) [Can't send tweet anymore: plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448394/can-send-tweet-anymore-plugin-com-apple-share-twitter-post-invalidated)

2) [IOS7 - SLComposeViewController - Error posting to Twitter - cannot send tweet - connection failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982288/ios7-slcomposeviewcontroller-error-posting-to-twitter-cannot-send-tweet)

3) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5275212

I did log out and log in in Settings->Twitter accounts. Also sharing content length is not the problem.

Does any one else experiencing/solved this issue? Appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Update:** This works on iOS 8.3. Not works on iOS 8.1.2

Comment: Did you check your twitter account under settings as suggested in the links you posted ?

Comment: Logout from twitter account setting->twitter and re-login. Also try to change the content each time when you post the tweet.

Comment: @kmithi already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue solved when

1. Date & Time set to automatically
2. Language changed to English India (my language)
3. Region Format changed to India (my region)

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this Link and Read All Comments and check it

http://forums.imore.com/ask-question/287207-when-tweeting-photo-i-get-tweet-cannot-sent-because-connection-twitter-failed.html